# how to serialize my treeview control in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
namespace TreeViewControl
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string n = textBox1.Text;
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode == null)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(n, n);
        }
        else
        {
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(n, n);
        }
    }
}
  }
```

//somebody pls help me with this i want to serialize this code

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you try anything?

Comment: Composite class model can help you I think

Answer (score -1):

I have got the way to serialize the tree posting here it might help someone...

string filename = Application.StartupPath+"\Tree.dat";
        private void btnAddNodes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                                                                       //tree has been created in the btn click event

```
        if (txtNodeName.Text==String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the Node Name in Textbox");
            txtNodeName.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            string n = txtNodeName.Text;
            if (treeView1.SelectedNode == null)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(n, n);
            }
            else
            {
                treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(n, n);
            }
        }
    }
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        int i=1; 
       private void btnSerialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //serialization is done here
        {
            i = 1;
        Stream file = File.Create(filename);
        ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
        foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            ar.Add(tn);                                     //conver tree to arraylist
        }
        bf.Serialize(file, ar);
        file.Close(); 
    }

        private void btnDeserialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //deserialization is done here
        {

            if (i == 1)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                Stream file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
                TreeNode tr = null;
                object obj = null;
                try
                {
                    obj = bf.Deserialize(file);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                ArrayList ar = obj as ArrayList;
                foreach (TreeNode tl in ar)
                {
                    if (tr == tl)
                        tr = tl;
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(tl);
                }
                file.Close();
                i++;
```

Comment: This can be improved. Maybe you want to get a more informed opinion over on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? Make sure you read their [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) first on how to post there.

Comment: This won't help anyone. The code mixes up the *data* and the control that displays it. Otherwise, you could simple serialize the data into whatever format you want. The entire problem is that you *don't* have the data and try to recreate it from the UI instead.